# Azure PIM Removing a Eligibility Schedule Request on an Azure Role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

I'm trying to manage PIM flows on Azure Roles using the rest API. Creating one works. I can ensure that a particular group is eligible to become, e.g., a Contributor on a subscription. Updating or deleting that, however, throws errors. If I understand the documentation correctly, I need the create endpoint for all actions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-eligibility-schedule-requests/create?view=rest-authorization-2020-10-01&tabs=HTTP

Here's my script:

```
    $url = "$baseUrl/$scope/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/${guid}?api-version=2020-10-01"

    $currentDateTime = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'

    $body = @{
        "properties" = @{
            "roleDefinitionId" = "$roleDefinitionId"
            "PrincipalId"      = "$principalId"
            "RequestType"      = "AdminRemove"
            "scheduleInfo"     = @{
                "StartDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
                "Expiration"    = @{
                    "Type"        = "AfterDuration"
                    "EndDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
                    "Duration"    = "P1D"
                }
            }
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    # Create the resource if it doesn't exist
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Here, I use the AdminRemove RequestType trying to remove the setting. It throws:
"A role assignment request with Id:  already exist"

The same happens when I, for example, use AdminUpdate or AdminExtend.

How should I be able to remove the PIM flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one eligibility schedule request on Azure role added to **`DemoSri`** group as below:

[image]

When I ran your script to **remove** above eligibility schedule request, I too got **same error** like this:

```
$baseUrl = "https://management.azure.com"
$scope = "/subscriptions/subId"
$guid = "eligibilityScheduleRequestId"  
$url = "$baseUrl/$scope/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/${guid}?api-version=2020-10-01"
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}
$currentDateTime = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'
$roleDefinitionId = "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
$principalId = "groupId"
$body = @{
    "properties" = @{
        "roleDefinitionId" = "$roleDefinitionId"
        "PrincipalId"     = "$principalId"
        "RequestType"     = "AdminRemove"
        "scheduleInfo"    = @{
            "StartDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
            "Expiration"    = @{
                "Type"        = "AfterDuration"
                "EndDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
                "Duration"    = "P1D"
            }
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you have to provide a **new GUID** each time you delete or update the scheduleRequest.

To **resolve** the error, I ran below modified script and got **response** like this:

```
$baseUrl = "https://management.azure.com"
$scope = "/subscriptions/subId"
$guid = (New-Guid).Guid
$url = "$baseUrl/$scope/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/${guid}?api-version=2020-10-01"
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}
$currentDateTime = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'
$roleDefinitionId = "/subscriptions/subID/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
$principalId = "groupId"
$body = @{
    "properties" = @{
        "roleDefinitionId" = "$roleDefinitionId"
        "PrincipalId"     = "$principalId"
        "RequestType"     = "AdminRemove"
        "scheduleInfo"    = @{
            "StartDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
            "Expiration"    = @{
                "Type"        = "AfterDuration"
                "EndDateTime" = "$currentDateTime"
                "Duration"    = "P1D"
            }
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body

$response
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where eligibility schedule request **removed** successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My issue was indeed not generating a new guid every time.